# Adding the Up button but not Display in title bar of Second Activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to add up button in Second activity but it will not Display i don't now why... i tried different thins but still stuck... please Help..
Here is the code from second activity...

```
    package com.example.hamza.actionbarmenu;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;

public class secondActivity extends MainActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try `getSupportActionbar()` instead of `getActionBar()`

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

u can add below code in manifest file for going toparent activity

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />

    </activity>
```

Comment: I would this answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class secondActivity extends MainActivity
```

Try replace the line above for:

```
public class secondActivity extends Activity
```

Comment: trying using AppCompact activity

Answer (score 0):

Try to add parentActivity to your SecondActivity in  manifest like this :

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="your package">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <!-- Main Activity -->

            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <!-- SecondActivity -->
            <activity
                android:name="SecondActivity"
       ===>         android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">                      
             </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

and use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`